# Join list from specific index

Tags: python, django, list, python-2.7

I have a list like below:

```
ingredients = ['apple','cream','salt','sugar','cider']
```

I want to join this list to get a string but I want to join from 2nd index till the last one.

to get this : `"salt sugar cider"`
Length of list may vary.

Is it possible to do this with join function or I have to do it by looping over elements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just [*slice* the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> l = ['apple', 'cream', 'salt', 'sugar', 'cider']
>>> ' '.join(l[2:])
'salt sugar cider'
```

We don't specify the end of the slice which means that it would slice to the last element of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot @alecxe.